# Map<String, Object> as @RequestBody is missing

Tags: java, spring, http

In my service 'A', I have @RestController with method:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/reservationsCheck")
    public List<LockerReservations> getReservationsCheck(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestMap) {
        return bookingService.availabilityCheckSizeTime(
                Size.valueOf((String) requestMap.get("size")),
                LocalDateTime.parse((CharSequence) requestMap.get("start")),
                LocalDateTime.parse((CharSequence) requestMap.get("end")));
    }
```

and when called from Postman It works very well:
[image]

But when I try to call it from service 'B':

```
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/v1/api/";

        public List<LockerReservations> getReservationsCheck(Size size, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {

            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            Map<String, Object> sizeTimeMap = new HashMap<>();
            sizeTimeMap.put("size", size);
            sizeTimeMap.put("start", start);
            sizeTimeMap.put("end", end);
            HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(sizeTimeMap, httpHeaders);
            return List.of(restTemplate.getForObject(url + "reservationsCheck", LockerReservations[].class, httpEntity));
        }
```

I get (from the 'B' side):

```
400 : [{"timestamp":"2023-03-13T18:53:30.701+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/v1/api/reservationsCheck"}]
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : [{"timestamp":"2023-03-13T18:53:30.701+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/v1/api/reservationsCheck"}]
```

and(from the 'A' side):

```
2023-03-13T19:53:30.700+01:00  WARN 21648 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : 
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Required request body is missing: 
public java.util.List<com.example.mongoExample.domain.LockerReservations> com.example.mongoExample.controller.SmartLockerController.getReservationsCheck(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)]
```

I don't get It. I tried mapping this HashMap to Json and It didn't help. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are on the thin ice here. `GET` requests must not have bodies. Probably, Spring just ignores it. Can you change to `@PostMapping` and make `POST` request from service B?

Comment: The last argument in the `getForObject` method you're calling isn't the request body, it's a URI parameter. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Switch to POST like @AlexanderPavlov said, and provide the body as _second_ argument to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov that was it. Thank you, didn't know that about `GET` method. Postman has confused me